# What is the scope of the term 'orbits'?

Tags: orbital-motion, terminology, soft-question

Warning - this is a very soft question. I was wondering what the precise meaning of the word [orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit) is? Wikipedia refers to it only in the sense of gravitational forces, in which case mathematically orbits would be limited to particle trajectories under under an attractive, conservative, central force that goes as the inverse square of the distance. However I have seen (in my lecture notes) motion under a general central force of some power as being referred to as 'orbit', and even under repulsive force. I have certainly heard the term 'hyperbolic orbit'. Orbits can, of course, also be bound and unbound, so it cannot simply be referring to a closed trajectory, which I think is assumed in the more strict use of the term.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the term might have different scope in different contexts?

Comment: Wikipedia gives a good definition in the scope of physics.